# In OpenCart, I have a permission denied message

Tags: opencart, upgrade, dashboard

In OpenCart, I have a permission denied message.
I upgraded from Opencart 2.0.2.0 to opencart 2.2.2.0
Suddenly I cannot view anything except for the dashboard
[Please click to see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU1m4.png)

I don't know what cause this issue and why it happened after upgrading the CMS

I tried to add a user via PhPMyadmin and it did not work

Please advise

Regards

Comment: can you enter the System area of your admin?oh didnt check the image

Comment: Go in your database and find user_group table and see if your are set as an administrator